# Unable to mount disk by uuid in fstab

Tags: 16.04, mount, fstab

I have a HDD from my old openmediavault (based on Debian Jessie) machine with GPT ext4 format.  I used it in my new ubuntu machine and try to mount it in fstab but odd things happened.  If I mount it by /dev/sdb1, it works.  But, if I mount it by UUID, the booting always fails.  Anyone had the same problem?  Thanks.

My sudo blkid /dev/sdb1 as:

```
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="HD0103T" UUID="adc291f2-b240-4b85-92af-ab2f7df0b831" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ba0451ca-d562-4a7a-a21e-ca52c1f0e5ae"
```

and my /etc/fstab mount line as(If I replace the uuid part with "/dev/sdb1", it works):

```
UUID=adc291f2-b240-4b85-92af-ab2f7df0b831 /media/cwy/HD0103T ext4 defaults 0 2
```

Comment: Please update your question with the uuid mount line from /etc/fstab and the output of `sudo blkid /dev/sdb1`

Comment: It looks totally right. Have you tried to copy the UUID="..." from blkid (including quotation marks) to fstab ? Beside of that I have no ideas.

Comment: I will try to copy it.  Happy new year !

Comment: UUID's must be unique, please check if the same UUID is used for another partition (file-system) with `lsblk -f`.

Comment: I can confirm this one. Fails with UUID and works with device file on LTS 16.04 with 4 TB disk partioned with GPT and ext4 filesystem. Don't know why and didn't find a solution ...

Comment: I have similar problem with fat32 partition. Strange. Did you solve the problem?